# Select specific <option> from <select> while having a value from PHP

Tags: php, html

I have the following HTML code for my  element and it is populated with  elements.

```html
<select name="category" class = "form-control">
  <option value = "Awearness">Awearness</option>
  <option value = "ITandTechnology">IT and Technology</option>
  <option value = "Physics">Physics</option>
  <option value = "Sport">Sport</option>
  <option value = "Science">Science</option>
  <option value = "Social">Social</option>
</select>
```

I also have PHP code above  tag that gets me value of category from MySQL database. So for example:

```
...$category = "Sport";...
```

What I need to know is, is there a way to select certain option when page loads that corresponds to $category variable I got in PHP?
So if

```
...$category = "Sport";...
```

it selects the Sport option from  tags.

Comment: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {document.querySelector('.form-control option[value = "Sport"]').selected = true;})

Comment: where's the php that you've tried?

Comment: Are you asking how to set an option as selected on page load? Then it's just to do: `<option value="Sport" <?= $category == 'Sport' ? 'selected' : '' >>` and do the same for the other options as well.

Comment: @gaetanoM I am aware of the selected attribute of <option> element, but I am not looking for that. Thank you

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That's it! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set an option as selected on page load we can use the `selected` attribute.

```
<option value="some-value" <?= $category == 'some-value' ? 'selected' : '' >>....</option>
```

Then do the same for each option in your list.

Comment: Probably better to code a `foreach` loop just for easy modify things later.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using JavaScript along with your php.
For example,

```
<?php
$cat = 'Sport';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select name="category" class = "form-control" id = "i1">
  <option value = "Awearness">Awearness</option>
  <option value = "ITandTechnology">IT and Technology</option>
  <option value = "Physics">Physics</option>
  <option value = "Sport">Sport</option>
  <option value = "Science">Science</option>
  <option value = "Social">Social</option>
</select>

 <script>
    var a= document.getElementById('i1');
a.getElementsByTagName('option');

for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{

   if(a[i].value=='<?php echo $cat;?>')
   {
       a[i].setAttribute("selected","selected");
           break;
   } 

}

</script>   



</body>
</html>
```